# Amazon Kinesis emulator

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis

We are evaluating real-time event processing engines (like twitter storm)
One of the options is recently released [Amazon Kinesis](http://aws.amazon.com/kinesis/).

I'm wondering if there is any sort of emulator/sandbox environment available that would allow to play around with kinesis a bit without the need to set up AWS account and paying for the use of the service

Thank you in advance

Comment: It's hard to imagine how a sandbox/emulator makes any sense at all when you can test on the [real service](http://aws.amazon.com/kinesis/pricing/) for $0.015 per hour per shard, $0.028 per *million* PUT transactions, and the first 15 GB of outbound data transfer are included in the [AWS Free Tier](http://aws.amazon.com/free/).

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Some of us have to wait weeks for our devops / system admins to set up the service on our corporate accounts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've been using [kinesalite](https://github.com/mhart/kinesalite) for a while now and it seems to work quite well.

Since I don't really like to have node packages into my machine, I've also created a [docker image](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/dlsniper/kinesalite/) for it.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -3):

EMR recently launched Kinesis integration for tools in Hadoop ecosystem, you may want to try and see if your usecases can be addressed there. http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2014/02/process-streaming-data-with-kinesis-and-elastic-mapreduce.html